# ISO date format filed in CSV, I need to convert that ISO field to IST and store it in the same csv file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have ISO date format filed in CSV, I need to convert that ISO field to IST and store it in the same csv file, through Bash script. Is there any way to do it through awk

Comment: you didn't show any input

Comment: 2017-06-15T02:52:12.163Z field is this, and I have to make it in IST adding 5:30+ to the same iso field

Comment: post the input and expected result to your question

Comment: I have date values  in ISO in csv in one column as :                             
"2017-06-12T05:00:37.139Z"  and need output in IST ie. added 5:30+ to it, so my output should be "2017-06-12T10:30:37.139Z

Comment: What @RomanPerekhrest asked you is : edit your question with a sample of the CSV input file and the same CSV sample as expected in output. How do you expect we know what is the CSV format to parse or which column is targeted without these informations ;)

Comment: @Esteban, I have mention above, given one sample value that i have input and expected output, i just wanted to process my csv file filed  through bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do this with `awk`, but you're asking in the context of a Bash script, so maybe this helps?

```
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ cat input.csv
"2017-06-12T05:00:37.139Z"
"1980-01-01T00:30:00.100Z"
"2010-12-31T23:59:59.341Z"
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ cat csvtest.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -Euo pipefail

while read -r field1 field2
do
  printf '"%s","%s"\n' \
    "${field1//\"/}" \
    "$(env TZ=Asia/Kolkata date -d "${field1//\"/}" +"%FT%T.%-3NZ%z")" \
    >> "${2:-output.csv}"
done < "${1:-input.csv}"

neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ ./csvtest.sh
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ cat output.csv
"2017-06-12T05:00:37.139Z","2017-06-12T10:30:37.139Z+0530"
"1980-01-01T00:30:00.100Z","1980-01-01T06:00:00.100Z+0530"
"2010-12-31T23:59:59.341Z","2011-01-01T05:29:59.341Z+0530"
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $
```

Comment: Thanks Neech! Just one more query, is their any way that i can replace this to my input file only, and I have 25 fields in my input csv and I have this values in second field only. So i need to replace that field only rest will need as it is.